# Extract Key Value Pairs from a named Collection MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I am pulling form values from a loosely bound razor form. The reason I am not using strongly bound model is that the payment value fields and categories are dynamic.

The  form collection array reaching the controller is as below:

```
Payment {"1":"120","4":"23","6":"12","8":"120","9":"100"}
```

I need to split the array like (When PayCatId =1, Pay =120) (When PayCatId =4, Pay=23) etc..

```
string [] pa =collection["Payment"].Split(char.Parse(","));
string [] pc =collection.AllKeys["Payment"].Split(char.Parse(","));
```

Then I am trying to save to database using the logic below;

```
for (var i = 0; i < pa.Length; i++)
{
    payment.Pay = Convert.ToDecimal(pa[i]);                 
    payment.PayCatId = Convert.ToInt32(pa[i]);  (added:how do i get this value from pair?)
    payment.PayDate = DateTime.Now;
    db.Payments.Add(payment);
    db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Removed the Error bit as I have been enlightened that that approach  is not applicable
I also want to know if this is the right and reliable approach to achieve  this objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through two steps at a time instead of one

```
for (var i = 0; i < pa.Length; i+=2)
{
    payment.Pay = Convert.ToDecimal(pa[i]);                 
    payment.PayCatId = Convert.ToInt32(pa[i+1]);
    payment.PayDate = DateTime.Now;
    db.Payments.Add(payment);
    db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of Split, Select and ToDictionary to do this, see the code:

```
var srt = "\"1\":\"120\",\"4\":\"23\",\"6\":\"12\",\"8\":\"120\",\"9\":\"100\"";

srt.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(x => int.Parse(x[0].Replace("\"","")), x => int.Parse(x[1].Replace("\"","")))


/*
    Output: 
    Dictionary<int, int>(5) 
    { 
        { 1, 120 }, 
        { 4, 23 }, 
        { 6, 12 }, 
        { 8, 120 }, 
        { 9, 100 } 
    }
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoMonteiro it did not take long to realise I will need your code contribution too

Comment: @Diin I am that my contribution was useful